# Хранение в поле БД формулы и вычисление с пом. javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

Есть поле в которое вводится сумма, к немк применяются различные вычисления (например, взять процент от суммы и поделить на 2) для расчета комиссии
Вычисления в javascript, формула описывается в поле БД

Как сделать нечто универсальное?

Например, вводим 100   -  значение (100/10)*4 + 810  = ?,
для другого , например, просто - /2  или ещё чего. 
Заводить поля деления, процента, сложения и всё обрабатывать слишком грубо выглядит
У поля свои заморочки. Есть ещё интервалы, ввел 100 - на выходе 10, ввел от 101 до 1000 - 20. Тут ладно можно описать

Как быть с формулами не могу найти оптимальный вариант. Чтобы можно было в javascript подавать и вычислять? Может есть что-то подобно регулярным выражениям, но в плане формул, а не валидации данных

Comment: предусматриваете в формуле некие "переменные", строки которые при выполнении данными будут заменятся и потом eval выполняете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значит нам нужно много разных функций от одной переменной.

```js
var f1body = 'return (x/10)*4 + 810;';

var f1 = new Function('x', f1body);
var f2 = new Function('x', 'return x/2;');
var f3 = new Function('x', 'if (x < 101) return 10; if (x < 1001) return 20; return 30;');

var summa = 500;
alert(f1(summa));
alert(f2(summa));
alert(f3(summa));
```

`new Function` как можно догадаться создаёт функцию из строки. Первый аргумент - это имена параметров будущей функции (в нашем случае только один параметр). Второй аргумент - тело функции.

Надо ли говорить от том, что тела функций можно хранить в БД и загружать по необходимости?

Comment: Неплохой способ. Но надо понимать, что в подобном "лобовом" решении нельзя чтобы формулы заводил в БД пользователь - иначе это готовая XSS (если только формулы не индивидуальные).

Comment: А что делать? Кто не рискует, тот сам разрабатывает парсеры формул (хотя это не так уж и трудно на самом деле).

Comment: В данном случае нет никакого риска. Есть безопасный и небезопасный код.

Comment: Риск в том, что кодировщик может случайно или по злому умыслу накодировать опасный код. Ведь никаких гарантий от опасностей подобные решения предоставить в принципе не может. И способа запускать евалы и функции в песочнице, чтобы не тянули свои ручонки куда не положено, ещё не придумали?

Comment: Это не "риск". Это уязвимость.

Comment: Например Вы играете в русскую рулетку. Это как называется? Вы рискуете или человеческий организм имеет уязвимость против пули? Это ведь с какого конца посмотреть. Владелец такой уязвимом системы рискует быть убитым. Риск - действие владельца, программиста. Уязвимость - свойство системы. Термин риск не менее уместен.

Answer (score 0):

Самым правильным решением пока остается применение парсера математических формул. Если сами не можете сочинить, то можно найти готовый. Вот например http://mathjs.org/
Самое трудное здесь - `Есть ещё интервалы, ввел 100 - на выходе 10, ввел от 101 до 1000 - 20`.
Но наверное можно что-то придумать.

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать несколько полей (настраиваемое количество?) для ввода значений. А в самой формуле записывать их любым удобным способом. Например, `(a/800 + b*1.5)`. Соответственно, при вычислении формулы сначала считываете значения переменных из полей ввода и подставляете в строку - обычным `replace` или регулярным выражением (например, может получиться строка типа `(200/800 + 300*1.5)`). А потом скармливаете получившуюся формулу в eval().

Только рекомендую значения как-нибудь заэкранировать. Самым надёжным способом, пожалуй, будет удалить из них все символы, кроме разрешённых: цифры, точка, запятая, плюс, минус, буквы 'E' и 'e' (можно английские и русские). После удаления все запятые перевести в точки. Если планируете вводить в качестве значений математические выражения, тогда можно ещё оставлять в них знаки операций и скобки.

Comment: eval и строковые подстановки - зло

Comment: неаргументированное субъективное мнение.

Comment: особенно после комментария, что new Function - неплохой способ.

Answer (score -1):

Алгоритм уже описали, могу предложить вариант реализации:

Хранить формулы в следующем формате, где `{{0}}` - первое значение, `{{1}}` - второе, и так далее:

```
var expression = "100 - {{0}} * (100 / 10) + {{1}}";
```

Так же массив со значениями (как и где хранить, решать Вам, можно так же в бд в виде строки, а потом с помощью `eval` получать массив), например:

```
var values = [100, 800];
```

И функция которая заменяет "шаблон" на значение:

```
// подставляем значения из массива в формулу
var getFormula = function getFormula(str, values) {
  return values.reduce(function (str, number, i) {
    return str.replace('{{'+i+'}}', number);
  }, str);
};

// getFormula(expression, values); "100 - 100 * (100 / 10) + 800"
// getFormula("{{0}} * 5", [-2]); "-2 * 5"
```

И последний шаг в самом простом варианте:

```
var parsedExpression = getFormula(expression, values);
var finishValue = eval(parsedExpression); // -100
```

Конечно присутствует очень много нюансов (обработка невалидных данных, обработка отрицательных чисел и т.д.), но для примера реализация должно быть достаточно.

Comment: eval и строковые подстановки - зло

Comment: @pavel-mayorov `new Function()` это неплохой вариант, а `eval` - зло? :)

Comment: Конечно в идеале можно написать свой парсер формул, но для примера простой реализации можно использовать и `eval`, и если данные валидируются, то проблем никаких быть не должно.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Функция работает быстрее; кроме того она будет корректнее работать с "неправильными" значениями.

Comment: Согласитесь, что в контексте этой задаче "быстрота" будет минимальна. Тем более, в формулировке вопроса не было утверждений, что нужно привести в пример самый оптимальный вариант в плане быстродействия.
_кроме того она будет корректнее работать с "неправильными" значениями_ приведите пожалуйста пример, не могу сходу придумать.

Comment: Формула: {{0}} * 2 + 5. Подставляем 1 + 3 и наблюдаем совершенно бессмысленные вычисления. Аналогичная же функция вернет NaN.

Comment: Вот еще пример: `Math.sqrt({{0}}+1)`. Подставляем `)+(`

Comment: А уж если формула строковая - тут точно все пропало. `"{{0}}".length` вернет полную фигню для **совершенно нормальной** строки `1"+"2`

Comment: Согласен, если использовать мой пример без дополнений, и не валидировать данные, то такое возможно. Но первые две ошибки исправляются `values.filter((n) => !isNaN(n));`, как и формулу можно провалидировать на корректность. Я об этом написал в конце ответа. Но, я вас понял, спасибо за примеры

Comment: Да, валидация тут поможет. И еще экранирование для строк. Но вы не замечаете, что на пустом месте вырастает все больше кода? Создать же функцию и ее вызвать можно двумя строками (причем вторая строка нужна только если мы функцию запоминаем).